# batch code in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I do not want to just call a batch file from java, I want the code to be in java.

I have this so far but my batch file has a lot of code and does not accept it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    final String dosCommand = "cmd /c dir /s";
    final String location = "C:\\WINDOWS";
    try {
      final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dosCommand + " " + location);
      final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
      int ch;
      while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char)ch);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sample of the batch code I want to add in my java class. I am not adding the @echo off to my class, unless someone tells me I need to.

```
@echo off

rundll32 wbemupgd, UpgradeRepository

NET USE Q: \\Somenetworkpath\ /PERSISTENT:NO
Q:
CD \DeskTop\Troubleshoot\
COPY subinacl.msi "C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Desktop"
C:
MSIEXEC.EXE /i "\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Desktop\subinacl.msi" /qn

DEL /Q "C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Desktop\subinacl.msi"

C:
CD \Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\
SUBINACL /SUBKEYREG HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE /GRANT=Administrators=F
SUBINACL /SUBKEYREG HKEY_CURRENT_USER /GRANT=Administrators=F
SUBINACL /SUBKEYREG HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /GRANT=Administrators=F
SUBINACL /SUBDIRECTORIES %SystemDrive% /GRANT=Administrators=F
SUBINACL /SUBKEYREG HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE /GRANT=System=F
SUBINACL /SUBKEYREG HKEY_CURRENT_USER /GRANT=System=F
SUBINACL /SUBKEYREG HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT /GRANT=System=F
SUBINACL /SUBDIRECTORIES %SystemDrive% /GRANT=System=F
```

Comment: When you say 'does not accept it', what do you mean? Your output is a bit nonsensical.

Comment: Do you have a valid reason for embedding a batch script inside a Java file? Seems to me like an example of a bad practice to create such a mix. Having them separate would allow you to change the script without recompiling the Java class.

Comment: @machinery I just want to have less files if possible and do not know another way to rethink the batch file in java. Recompiling the java file is not an issue for me, it's prefered to prevent modification.

Comment: @nathaniel If i copy and paste the code I get a lot of errors, mostly syntax, even though it is surrounded by quotes. For example one of the errors dislikes the use of "\" and other syntax errors.

Comment: @jerhynsoen Those errors are probably going to be as useful as the output for achieving your end goal. You should probably also post what you expect to get out.

Comment: There are compile errors not output errors. It does not seem to accept the code from the batch file, just gives me errors after I type it in. Tried to clean it up, but it just hates me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted does not seem possible. Ended up just calling the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have not escaped special characters in your batch code properly for java.

`"` is escaped as `\"`

`'` is escaped as `\'`

`\` is escaped as `\\`